# Override Salesforce's Page Layout Assignment scheme when showing Record Detail within Lightning Page

Tags: lightning, pagelayoutassignment

We've developed a custom Lightning component which displays the Record Detail of multiple objects in separate tabs.

The default behavior of Salesforce (when viewing a page that has the Record Detail of an object) is to show the Page Layout that corresponds with the user's Profile or to the Record Type of the record being viewed (According to the Page Layout Assignment scheme).

Is there a way to override this default behavior?

We would like to show a specific Page Layout instead (Even if it has to be hard-coded).

The only solution we have found involves using Field Sets (which means we would lose the ability to use the Page Layout Editor to change the layout of a record's detail).

Answer (score 1):

With Spring 17, you will be able to assign page layouts by App/Profile/Record Type. That could provide you a new dimension of control

Comment: Yes I saw the option to assign a Lightning page by App.  Unfortunately this doesn't help.
Also keep in mind that assigning a Lightning page is not the same as a Page Layout - which refers to the layout of the fields of a Record Detail.